# SQL: Joins with two basic tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Got two SQL tables , structure and values are mentioned below.

Table 1 : Employee

```
    CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `EmpId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EmpName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DeptId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Jod` date NOT NULL,
  `Salary` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `employee` (`EmpId`, `EmpName`, `DeptId`, `Jod`, `Salary`) VALUES
(1, 'ABCD', 1, '2015-02-23', 50000),
(2, 'EFGH', 1, '2016-04-11', 40000),
(3, 'HIJK', 2, '2016-05-22', 35000),
(4, 'LMNO', 3, '2016-05-22', 30000),
(5, 'PQRS', 3, '2016-06-03', 30000);
```

Table 2 : Department

```
CREATE TABLE `dept` (
  `DeptId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeptName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `dept` (`DeptId`, `DeptName`) VALUES
(1, 'Sales'),
(2, 'Account'),
(3, 'Support');
```

Now out of these two I need to **query to print every Department name and the count of employees in that department.**

And I have tried with the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(dept.DeptName),COUNT(employee.EmpId) FROM dept JOIN employee on dept.DeptId = employee.DeptId
```

which yields the result

```
DeptName  COUNT(employee.EmpId)
Sales      5
```

But Actual result what i need is

```
DeptName  COUNT(employee.EmpId)
Sales      2
Accounts   1
Support    2
```

How to achieve it, Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Get rid of `distinct` and use `group by`....  And remove the `sql server` tag, this only works in `mysql`...

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag the specific database only.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT - and applies to the whole selected rows. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT dept.DeptName, ... ` to make code clearer.

Comment: However, no need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, the GROUP BY returns no duplicate rows.

Comment: There are lots of examples available in both stackoverflow and other web platform. It is a very silly question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT d.DeptName, COUNT(e.EmpId)
FROM dept d JOIN
     employee e
     ON e.DeptId = d.DeptId
GROUP BY d.DeptName;
```

I'm not sure what your thought-process is on using `DISTINCT`.  First, it applies to all the columns being selected; it is not a function.  The parentheses are immaterial.

Second, you are using an aggregation function (`COUNT()`) and thought should automatically point you in the direction of `GROUP BY`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6acc2f3a88f68c05d7082e29709c45eb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: For this the outcome will be  `DeptName
COUNT(e.EmpId)
Account
5
Sales
5
Support
5`